# Opencart 403 Forbidden for Admin

Tags: php, .htaccess, permissions, opencart

I haven't touched any files on an install of Opencart for over 2 years or so but recently have been getting an error when trying to access my /admin page.

I tried removing -Indexes from the public_html .htaccess file and also added a .htaccess file to the /admin folder but with no luck.

I've read that it could be something to do with file permissions but unsure how this could have changed without me accessing any of the files?

Comment: If you didn't modify any file, upload admin folder from opencart installation pack, if this doesn't work, send a ticket to your hosting.

Comment: Thanks mate, luckily I had a backup from a few months ago and weirdly enough replacing the admin folder worked. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the admin folder fixed this issue. Thanks for the answer Mojtaba Sabeti